# Парсинг json и выполнение повторных запросов не разрывая соединение kotlin

Tags: парсер, kotlin, https

Хочу написать парсинг данных с одной страницы сайта, доступ к ней появляется только после логина по https.
Методом подключения через HttpsUrlConnection описанным в базе знаний андройда не подключалось, целевой сайт ругался на то что соединение не безопасно. В дополнении к авторизации сайт просит токен, который сам же выдаёт в случае если он указан не правильно и меняет его после каждого подключения. Нашел такой способ подключения и вытягивания токена в result :

```
fun sendPostRequest(userName:String, password:String, csrf: String) {

            var reqParam = URLEncoder.encode("login", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8")
            reqParam += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")
            reqParam += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("csrf", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(csrf, "UTF-8")
            val mURL = URL("https://auth2.bitrix24.net/bitrix/services/main/ajax.php?action=b24network.authorize.check")

            with(mURL.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection) { //Or HttpsURLConnection
                // optional default is GET
                this.requestMethod = "POST"

                val wr = OutputStreamWriter(this.outputStream)
                wr.write(reqParam)

                println("URL : $url")
                println("Response Code : $responseCode")

                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(this.inputStream)).use {
                    val response = StringBuffer()
                    var respcsrf: String = ""
                    var inputLine = it.readLine()
                    while (inputLine != null) {

                        response.append(inputLine)
                        respcsrf = inputLine
                        inputLine = it.readLine()
                    }

                    println("Response : $response")
                    val parser: Parser = Parser()
                    val resp: String = respcsrf.toString()
                    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(respcsrf)
                    val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
                    var string: String = json.array<String>("errors")?.obj("customData")?.string("csrf").toString()

                     result = string.removeSurrounding(
                            "JsonArray(value=[", // prefix
                            "])" // suffix
                    )


                    println("Строка из принятых данных " + result)




                    it.close()

            }


        }
    }
```

Далее надо снова залогинится с этим же токеном, как я понимаю чтоб токен не сменился мне надо продолжить общение с сайтом в этом же потоке с openConnection, но я не понимаю как это делается. При попытке в тойже функции переписать reqParam и ниже по коду подсунуть его wr.write(reqParam), а потом так же считать, то есть повторить тот же код что в функции выше 2 раза только с другими обновленными параметрами выходит ошибка
Caused by: java.io.IOException: closed.
Можно пример как это реализовать?

Comment: А сейчас у вас что, как не все тот же HttpsUrlConnection? Вам нужно документацию по использованию сервиса читать, только там есть ответы как и что надо делать. Все остальное, лишь инструменты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел хороший вариант с помощью библиотеки ktor. Имеет богатый функционал, 1 строчкой можно принять куки и сохранить их для следующих запросов.